# why I am getting mistmatch error in this scala code?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val l1 = Array(1, 3, -5, 7, -2, 8)
val (neg1, pos1) = l1.partition( _ < 0 )
val n = neg1(0)
val a1 = (pos1 + n)
```

In the last line I am getting the error "type mismatch; found : Int required: String". Is there any implicit conversion? How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`Array` append should use `:+`, like:

```
val a1 = pos1 :+ n
```